# Customizing preview-latex command to use LaTeX when in TeX-Pdf mode

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

In short: Is there a way to tell `preview-latex` to *NOT* use `pdflatex` instead of just toggling `TeX-Pdf` mode every time I want to re-generate previews?

I have a somewhat odd setup. AucTeX + GNU Emacs 24 on Mac OSX 10.6.8, operating with Skim as my pdf viewer.

I am using a makefile for document compilation that calls `latex` + `bibtex` + `simpdftex` to generate a PDF with synctex enabled. (I use `psfrag` and `.eps` files which is why `latex` is used instead of `pdflatex`). When Auctex is in `TeX-Pdf` mode (`C-c C-t C-p`) I can use synctex for forward and inverse search and `C-c C-c` and a `Make` command for quick compilation. (Without being in `TeX-Pdf` mode, forward-seach (`C-c C-v`) stops with a `.dvi` not found error) So far, everything works great, as expected.

However, preview-latex doesn't like this setup. When in `TeX-Pdf` mode, `preview-latex` wants to use `pdflatex` as the compilation command, but this doesn't work with my document and errors with a no images found. If I turn off `TeX-Pdf` mode, re-run `preview-latex` (`C-c C-p C-d`), PNGs are created and correctly placed in the document.

The Preview LaTeX Command customization option seems to be specifically related to what is inserted into the tex document and not the external compilation tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off pdf output by customizing `preview-LaTeX-command-replacements` like `M-x customize-variable RET preview-LaTeX-command-replacements RET`.  Then add a Named Replacement, and use the name `preview-LaTeX-disable-pdfoutput`.  I can't remember since it's been a while, but you might have to change `preview-image-type` to `dvipng` as well.  I may have done that to avoid some other problem on my machine.

I think that should work but if not, you can customize `preview-LaTeX-command` and change the `%l` to `%(latex) %S` or something similar.  Hopefully that wouldn't mess up the rest of the processing since it's hoping for pdf output.